# How to avoid code duplication in DRF views

Tags: django-rest-framework

class AddUsersView(UpdateAPIView):
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

```
def patch(self, request: Request, *args, **kwargs):
    if ...
        return successful_response({'data': "users added"})
    else:
        raise MeetingRoomDoesNotExist
```

class SubtractUsersView(UpdateAPIView):
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

```
def patch(self, request: Request, *args, **kwargs):
    if ...
        return successful_response({'data': "users subtracted"})
    else:
        raise MeetingRoomDoesNotExist
```

It seems my code is not DRY.What can I use to avoid code duplication.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

DRF views are not different from other python classes. Your two best options here are basically to :

- Integrate the duplicated code in a function you'd call in both patch functions instead of rewriting it
- Override the `patch()` function in a class and make your views inherit from it